# Is scipy.linalg.eig giving the correct left eigenvectors?

Tags: numpy, scipy, eigenvector

I have a question regarding the way how scipy.linalg.eig computes left and right eigenvectors. Maybe I misunderstood everything, but things seem not to be right to me...

From the beginning. To get eigenvalues and both eigenvectors I used the following:

`ev, left_v, right_v = scipy.linalg.eig(A, left=True)`

According to the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html), after setting `left=True` while calling the function I should expect to get left eigenvectors as columns of `left_v` where the ith column refers to the ith eigenvalue. However, the results were not what i anticipated so I did a simple check.

I computed right and left eigenvectors invoking the function twice (look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html) for details):

```
right_ev, right_v_2 = scipy.linalg.eig(A)
left_ev, left_v_2 = scipy.linalg.eig(A.T)
```

where columns of`left_v_2` are eigenvectors associated with corresponding values in `left_ev`.
Worth stressing that both `right_ev_2` and `left_ev_2` give the same eigenvalues, however they are in different order, which needs to be accounted for.

Comparing `left_ev` and `left_ev_2` (after reordering with respect to eigenvalues) one can quickly spot that the former is the conjugate of the latter and therefore `left_ev` obtained from `scipy.linalg.eig` with `left=True` is not a valid left eigenvector.

Another check on the validity of the eigenvectors can be done based on the fact that for an arbitrary real square matrix left and right eigenvectors are biorthogonal, i.e.:

`left_v.T.dot(right_v)` should give a diagonal matrix, but it doesn't,
until i change it to: `left_v.T.conj().dot(right_v)`,

while:

`left_v_2.T.dot(right_v_2)` gives an anticipated diagonal matrix.

Did anyone encounter similar problem before? Am I right with what I say? Is the sciPy manual a bit imprecise while describing `eig`? Can you give any advice?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About `vl`, the `eig` docstring says:

```
a.H vl[:,i] = w[i].conj() b.H vl[:,i]
```

Or, taking the *conjugate transpose* (i.e. Hermitian transpose) of both sides (which is what .H means), and assuming `b` is the identity,

```
vl[:,i].H a = w[i] vl[:,i].H
```

So the rows of the conjugate transpose of `vl` are the actual left eigenvectors of `a`.

Numpy arrays don't actually have the .H attribute, so you must use .conj().T.

Here's a script to verify the calculation:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig

# This only affects the printed output.
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)

a = np.array([[6, 2],
              [-1, 4]])

w, vl, vr = eig(a, left=True)

print "eigenvalues:", w
print

# check the left eigenvectors one-by-one:
for k in range(a.shape[0]):
    val = w[k]
    # Use a slice to maintain shape; vec is a 2x1 array.
    # That allows a meaningful transpose using .T.
    vec = vl[:, k:k+1]
    # rowvec is 1x2; it is the conjugate transpose of vec.
    # This should be the left eigenvector.
    rowvec = vec.conj().T
    # Verify that rowvec is a left eigenvector
    lhs = rowvec.dot(a)
    rhs = val * rowvec
    print "Compare", lhs, "to", rhs
    print rowvec, "is",
    if not np.allclose(lhs, rhs):
        print "*NOT*",
    print "a left eigenvector for eigenvalue", val

print
print "Matrix version:"
print "This"
print vl.conj().T.dot(a)
print "should equal this"
print np.diag(w).dot(vl.conj().T)
```

Output:

```
eigenvalues: [ 5.+1.j  5.-1.j]

Compare [[ 1.6330+2.4495j  4.0825+0.8165j]] to [[ 1.6330+2.4495j  4.0825+0.8165j]]
[[ 0.4082+0.4082j  0.8165-0.j    ]] is a left eigenvector for eigenvalue (5+1j)
Compare [[ 1.6330-2.4495j  4.0825-0.8165j]] to [[ 1.6330-2.4495j  4.0825-0.8165j]]
[[ 0.4082-0.4082j  0.8165+0.j    ]] is a left eigenvector for eigenvalue (5-1j)

Matrix version:
This
[[ 1.6330+2.4495j  4.0825+0.8165j]
 [ 1.6330-2.4495j  4.0825-0.8165j]]
should equal this
[[ 1.6330+2.4495j  4.0825+0.8165j]
 [ 1.6330-2.4495j  4.0825-0.8165j]]
```

Now, the `eig` docstring also says in the description of the return values:

```
vl : double or complex ndarray
    The normalized left eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue
    ``w[i]`` is the column v[:,i]. Only returned if ``left=True``.
    Of shape ``(M, M)``.
```

and that is potentially misleading, since the conventional definition of a left eigenvector (e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftEigenvector.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Left_and_right_eigenvectors) is a row vector, so it is the conjugate transpose of the column of `vl` that is actually the left eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks, Warren. I understood that you confirm that the conjugate transpose of `vl` is the left eigenvector according to commonly used convention. Now the question is why `eig` doscstring provided this ambiguous information?

Comment: Fwiw, `A = np.array([ [0., -1], [1, 0] ]);
w, L, R = eig(A, left=True, right=True);
print "L* . R: \n", L.conj().T.dot(R)`
gives `- I` -- trouble if you're expecting `I` .
In general it might be `np.diag( 1 -1 -1 1 )` so no quick fix ?
(Versions: numpy 1.14.1  scipy 1.0.0   python 2.7.14   mac 10.10.5)

Comment: In general, `L.conj().T.dot(R)` must be *diagonal*, but not necessarily the identity.   There exist left and right eigenvectors such that the product is the identity, but `eig` is not guaranteed to compute such eigenvectors.